# Where are the pre- and post-deployment scripts in VS2013 Database Projects?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, msdeploy

According to everything I've read about the "SQL Server Database Project" template in Visual Studio 2013, there should be a 'Scripts' folder when you create the project containing pre- and -post deployment SQL scripts that you want to be executed on publication.

When I create a new, blank DB project, the only structures I can see are the 'properties' and 'References' nodes:

[image]

I've tried manually adding SQL scripts according in the correct folders according to the articles I've read online, but still no joy. I would say the MSDN docs seem to refer mainly to VS2010 or at best 2012 DB projects, for example [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833410%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which assumes that the 'Scripts' folder has been populated as part of the project creation.

I've also tried installing the November 2014 updates to SQL Server database tooling via the VS2013 updates menu, and creating a new DB project, with the same results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you try to add a new item to the project, two of the script templates on offer are a Pre-Deployment script and a Post-deployment script.

[image]

Alternatively, if you just add a normal script to the project, you can later mark it for Pre-/Post- deployment via the "Build Action" property:

[image]

There are no longer dedicated folders for these scripts.

Comment: Also note the scripts won't be appended when you generate the script or 'update' from Schema Compare. It's only appended when you 'deploy'.